# how i want to get value from spesific data from firebase and calculations then reused it display in text

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<String> getTotal(String vals) async {
int counter = 0;
String vals = counter.toString();
Firestore.instance
    .collection('users').document(currentUser.uid).collection('input')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc) => counter += int.parse((doc["value"]))));
return vals; }
```

i want calculation each spesific data'value' in collection 'input',
but the 'value' is type sting, i change it use int.parse,
then, i want to get the result and used it in Text(),
how can i get the return?
thanks for your help

Comment: *Is this right or wrong?* isn't really a question. Does the code work?

Comment: i dont know how to get the return and want to use it

Comment: Firestore call is async. You should explicitly wait for it to complete before returning "vals".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for how to use `await` and `getDocuments` instead of `snapshots`:

```
Future<String> getTotal(String vals) async {
  int counter = 0;
  var snapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users').document(currentUser.uid).collection('input')
    .getDocuments();
  snapshots.forEach((doc) => counter += int.parse(doc["value"]));
  return counter.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and how to get the return and use it to display like in Text()?

Comment: You can't use this directly in the `build()` method. Instead you'll have to put the counter on the state, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487131/how-to-use-one-field-of-firebase-to-login/61487872#61487872