# Flutter initializing an object from firestore before widget builds

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and am building an app that creates projects. I am working on the view project page that allows the user to view each question. The way it is set up allows the user to view a question then click next (while remaining on the same page) to view the next question. The first initState initializes a Project object. This project object then needs to go get the data/information from the document. The questions are stored as a list of Question objects where each object has a type(text, multiple choice, numeric, photo upload etc), question, and number. The type of question is used to determine which widget to render (ex: photo upload would be a different form than text input.).

The issue I am having is that the project object is initialized but the list of question objects is not and I get indexing errors. However when I hot refresh I see the correct widget(currently just text). The other issue, which I think is related, is that each time the user clicks next the object goes and retrieves all the questions again so the list never ends. I believe the issue is in my getdataFromProject and questionData() functions in the getproject.dart (the first code snippet).

I have tried using a future builder but I am not sure this is the correct solution. However my build does depend on the object being finished. So I tried using a variable Future projectFuture and setting that equal to my _getQuestions() function (called in initState()).

Any help is appreciated.

```
class Questions {
  final String question;
  final String number;
  final String type;
  Questions({this.question, this.number, this.type});
  List<String> answers = new List();
}

class GetProject {
//this is what keeps growing each time next is pressed
List<Questions> questions; //holds the question objects 
  String docID;
   String title;
  GetProject(String title, String docID){
    this.docID = docID;
    this.title=title;
  questionData();

  } 





  Future<void> get getdataFromProject async {
    return await questionData();
  }



  Future<void> questionData() async {

    int count = 0;

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot =
        Firestore.instance.collection('Projects').document(this.docID).get();


    return await snapshot.then((DocumentSnapshot questionSnap) => {
          questionSnap.data.forEach((key, value) {
            if ('$key' == 'count') {
              count = value;
              count--;
              //returncount=count;
            } else if ('$key' == ('Question' + count.toString())) {
              print(value['Type']);
              Questions question = new Questions(
                type: value['Type'],
                number: value['Number'],
                question: value['Question'],
              );
              if (value['Type'] == 'MultipleChoice') {
                value['Answers'].forEach((e) {
                  question.answers.add(e.toString());
                });
                //question.answers.addAll(value['Answers']);
              }
              questions.add(question);

              count--;
            }
          }),
        });

  }


 int getType(int index) {
    switch (questions[index].type) {
      case 'TextInputItem':
        return 0;
      case 'MultipleChoice':
        return 1;
      case 'ShortAnswerItem':
        return 2;
      case 'UserLocation':
        return 3; 
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

```
class ViewProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docIDref;
  final String title;
  ViewProject({this.docIDref, this.title});

  @override
  _ViewProjectState createState() => _ViewProjectState();
}

class _ViewProjectState extends State<ViewProject> {
  GetProject project;
  int _currentQuestion = 0;
  Future projectFuture;


  int _getType(_currentQuestion) {
    switch(project.questions[_currentQuestion].type){
      case 'TextInputItem':
        return 0;
      case 'MultipleChoice':
        return 1;
      case 'ShortAnswerItem':
        return 2;
      case 'UserLocation':
        return 3; 
    }
    return -1;
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return new MaterialApp(

      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Random Widget")),
          body: 
          project.questions.length == 0

         ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()


         )
         :
          Center(child:

          FutureBuilder(
              initialData: 0,
              future: projectFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {


                if(project.questions.length>0){
                  return getQuestionWidget();
               }
              else{

                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
               }
              }
          )
      )),
    );
}


   Widget getQuestionWidget() {

    switch(_getType(_currentQuestion++)){
      case 0:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("TextInputItem", textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 1:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("MultipleChoice", textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 2:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("ShortAnswer", textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 3:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("UserLocation", textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case -1:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("Submit Page", textScaleFactor: 4),
          //getNextButton()
        ]);
    }
  }


Widget getNextButton(){
      return RaisedButton(
          child: Text("NEXT"),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            if(_currentQuestion < project.questions.length){
                return getQuestionWidget();
            }
            return Text("All done!"); 
            //setState(() {

              //_currentQuestion++;
              //return getQuestionWidget();

              //_getType(_currentQuestion);
           // });

          }
      );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    project = new GetProject(widget.title, widget.docIDref);
    //project.getdataFromProject();
    //_getQuestions();
    projectFuture=_getQuestions();
    super.initState();

  }

  Future<void> _getQuestions() async {

    return await project.getdataFromProject;


  }

  // Call this function when you want to move to the next page
  void goToNextPage() {

      _currentQuestion++;

  }


}
```

Comment: I prefer not to start the loading of data from the `build` method. See my answer from a similar question earlier today here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487131/how-to-use-one-field-of-firebase-to-login/61487872#61487872

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did try added that in the constructor. The issue is still that the object is not get the questions before the widget builds even when i put it in the constructor. Is there an issue with my getquestions() function maybe?

Comment: No issue, this is working as intended. Since the data comes from the cloud, it may take time before your app gets it. Your `build` method needs to be able to deal with the fact that the data isn't available yet. Either you have something conditional rendering like `isLoaded ? widgetWithData : "Loading..."` in the build of this widget, or the widget that uses this one skips this widget until its data is loaded.

Comment: So I've have the circular progess indicator rendering when the object is not finished. However that never stops and switches to the main widget unless I hot reload when debugging. Also are you suggesting that I not use a future builder at all and just use the switch statement widget?

Comment: It could well be that a `FutureBuilder` can also be used, I just found I got more productive when I started using `setState` directly. In your current approach, my guess is that your `return await snapshot.then...` never actually returns anything. But I'm definitely finding this harder to debug than calling `setState()`.

Comment: yes I get an error on that line (return await snapshot.then..) I added that in but I know that the .then doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: ok So I'm getting stuck on the loading screen. Once the object is build the loading screen never disappears. I've initialized the object in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I generally load futures in didChangeDependencies method.

something like:-

```
@override
didChangeDependencies() { 
   if (this.asyncdata == null) 
        loadData();
}

Future<void> loadData() async {
    this.asyncdata = await someAsyncFuntionThatReturnsData();
}
```

This should help. It is always easier to load stuff on day a button press as the functions for these can be async futures but the above patter should solve the double load with the if also.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate widget for each element and load data in initState.